# Showing preview of shared URL on social media for a React based application

Tags: reactjs, seo, share, serverless, preview

I am working on a react-based project which has a facebook feed kind of interface. My frontend is based on React and backend is on serverless, aws-sdk framework.

When clicks on a post and share it on social media,I need to generate previews dynamically based on the post data. I have seen that SSR is a solution, but all my project is based on CSR and I have no option to go to SSR now. Also, since the data is large, latency will get affected.

How to resolve this?

I tried using react-helmet and react-helmet-async. They are modifying the meta tags in the index.html, but still the previews are not generated based on the dynamic data. I also tried to dynamically modify the index.html using a function in the  tag. That also did not work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.